# Posgres database requires a group by clause. (column \"candidates.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function",)

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate, node.js, sequelize

I have 2 tables, agents and candidates. The candidates table has a foreign key "agent_id". I want to get all agents and aggregate the candidate counts on each agent object; the different candidate counts have different conditions to meet.

I am using nodejs, sequelize v4 and postgresql

The SQL query below throws an error that I do not understand.

**QUERY**

```sql
SELECT "Agent"."id", "Agent"."first_name", "Agent"."middle_name", "Agent"."last_name", "Agent"."phone", "Agent"."active", "Agent"."team_id", COUNT("candidates"."id") AS "total_count", COUNT("candidates"."active" = 'false') AS "pending_count", COUNT("candidates"."active" = 'true') AS "verified_count", "candidates"."id" AS "candidates.id", "candidates"."active" AS "candidates.active", "candidates"."client_approved" AS "candidates.client_approved", "candidates"."rejected" AS "candidates.rejected", "candidates"."date_disbursed" AS "candidates.date_disbursed", "candidates"."date_cashedout" AS "candidates.date_cashedout", "candidates"."agent_id" AS "candidates.agent_id" FROM "agents" AS "Agent" LEFT OUTER JOIN "candidates" AS "candidates" ON "Agent"."id" = "candidates"."agent_id" AND ("candidates"."deleted_at" > '2020-09-17 11:53:28.012 +00:00' OR "candidates"."deleted_at" IS NULL) WHERE ("Agent"."deleted_at" > '2020-09-17 11:53:28.012 +00:00' OR "Agent"."deleted_at" IS NULL) GROUP BY "Agent"."id" LIMIT '50';
```

**ERROR**
column "candidates.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

**ERROR DETAIL**

```
"name":"SequelizeDatabaseError","parent":{"name":"error","length":177,"severity":"ERROR","code":"42803","position":"303","file":"parse_agg.c","line":"1388","routine":"check_ungrouped_columns_walker","sql":"SELECT \"Agent\".\"id\", \"Agent\".\"first_name\", \"Agent\".\"middle_name\", \"Agent\".\"last_name\", \"Agent\".\"phone\", \"Agent\".\"active\", \"Agent\".\"team_id\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"id\") AS \"total_count\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"active\" = 'false') AS \"pending_count\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"active\" = 'true') AS \"verified_count\", \"candidates\".\"id\" AS \"candidates.id\", \"candidates\".\"active\" AS \"candidates.active\", \"candidates\".\"client_approved\" AS \"candidates.client_approved\", \"candidates\".\"rejected\" AS \"candidates.rejected\", \"candidates\".\"date_disbursed\" AS \"candidates.date_disbursed\", \"candidates\".\"date_cashedout\" AS \"candidates.date_cashedout\", \"candidates\".\"agent_id\" AS \"candidates.agent_id\" FROM \"agents\" AS \"Agent\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"candidates\" AS \"candidates\" ON \"Agent\".\"id\" = \"candidates\".\"agent_id\" AND (\"candidates\".\"deleted_at\" > '2020-09-17 11:53:28.012 +00:00' OR \"candidates\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL) WHERE (\"Agent\".\"deleted_at\" > '2020-09-17 11:53:28.012 +00:00' OR \"Agent\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL) GROUP BY \"Agent\".\"id\" LIMIT '50';"},"original":{"name":"error","length":177,"severity":"ERROR","code":"42803","position":"303","file":"parse_agg.c","line":"1388","routine":"check_ungrouped_columns_walker","sql":"SELECT \"Agent\".\"id\", \"Agent\".\"first_name\", \"Agent\".\"middle_name\", \"Agent\".\"last_name\", \"Agent\".\"phone\", \"Agent\".\"active\", \"Agent\".\"team_id\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"id\") AS \"total_count\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"active\" = 'false') AS \"pending_count\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"active\" = 'true') AS \"verified_count\", \"candidates\".\"id\" AS \"candidates.id\", \"candidates\".\"active\" AS \"candidates.active\", \"candidates\".\"client_approved\" AS \"candidates.client_approved\", \"candidates\".\"rejected\" AS \"candidates.rejected\", \"candidates\".\"date_disbursed\" AS \"candidates.date_disbursed\", \"candidates\".\"date_cashedout\" AS \"candidates.date_cashedout\", \"candidates\".\"agent_id\" AS \"candidates.agent_id\" FROM \"agents\" AS \"Agent\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"candidates\" AS \"candidates\" ON \"Agent\".\"id\" = \"candidates\".\"agent_id\" AND (\"candidates\".\"deleted_at\" > '2020-09-17 11:53:28.012 +00:00' OR \"candidates\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL) WHERE (\"Agent\".\"deleted_at\" > '2020-09-17 11:53:28.012 +00:00' OR \"Agent\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL) GROUP BY \"Agent\".\"id\" LIMIT '50';"},"sql":"SELECT \"Agent\".\"id\", \"Agent\".\"first_name\", \"Agent\".\"middle_name\", \"Agent\".\"last_name\", \"Agent\".\"phone\", \"Agent\".\"active\", \"Agent\".\"team_id\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"id\") AS \"total_count\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"active\" = 'false') AS \"pending_count\", COUNT(\"candidates\".\"active\" = 'true') AS \"verified_count\", \"candidates\".\"id\" AS \"candidates.id\", \"candidates\".\"active\" AS \"candidates.active\", \"candidates\".\"client_approved\" AS \"candidates.client_approved\", \"candidates\".\"rejected\" AS \"candidates.rejected\", \"candidates\".\"date_disbursed\" AS \"candidates.date_disbursed\", \"candidates\".\"date_cashedout\" AS \"candidates.date_cashedout\", \"candidates\".\"agent_id\" AS \"candidates.agent_id\" FROM \"agents\" AS \"Agent\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"candidates\" AS \"candidates\" ON \"Agent\".\"id\" = \"candidates\".\"agent_id\" AND (\"candidates\".\"deleted_at\" > '2020-09-17 11:53:28.012 +00:00' OR \"candidates\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL) WHERE (\"Agent\".\"deleted_at\" > '2020-09-17 11:53:28.012 +00:00' OR \"Agent\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL) GROUP BY \"Agent\".\"id\" LIMIT '50';","error@context":{}}
```

If I add the "candidates.id" to the group by clause it doesn't throw an error but it also doesn’t return the result I want. Please I would like to know why this error is happening and how to get my intended result without add the unnecessary grouping.

Comment: Remove all the `candidates.XXX` from the `SELECT` list, except the COUNTs.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an aggregate query, *every* select'ed column must *either* be included in the "group by" clause *or* be wrapped in an aggregating function.  You *cannot* have any 'select'ed column *not* in either of these states.

Why?

How would Postgres (or any other, sensible, DBMS for that matter) know *which* value to give you?

Consider this example:

```
select a, b, c, 
from table1 
order by a, b, c ; 

+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 
+---+---+---+

select a, b, count( c ) cc 
from table1 
group by a 
order by a ; 

+---+---+----+
| a | b | cc | 
+---+---+----+
| 1 | ? |  2 |
+---+---+----+
```

What value of "b" should replace the question mark, above?
Should it be 2 or 4?

There is nothing in the query to determine which one should be returned so Postgres will simply opt *not* to run the query at all, throwing this error instead.

I think you need [at least] two queries - one to get the Agent data and *counts* of Candidates and the other to get Candidate data.
BTW, you need to use "**SUM**(c.active = false)" to "add up" all the true/false values.  "COUNT(c.active = false)" will return the same value as "COUNT(c.active)" or, indeed, COUNT(anything-field-is-not-null)".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :) The SUM part especially really helped, I was wondering why all the numbers where the same lol